# Select all records for last two years and minimum date for specific status

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've been working on this for the last couple of days and no matter what I do, I'm getting the same wrong recordset.

Tables:

Account

```
id | Customer | dateOpened  
--------------------------
1  | ConAgra  | 11/01/2013  
2  | Fedex    | 06/21/2014
```

CaseStatus

```
id | caseStatus  
---------------  
1  | A  
2  | B  
3  | M  
4  | C  
5  | H  
6  | W
```

m_account_caseStatus

```
AccountID | caseStatusID | startDate | endDate  
----------------------------------------------  
1         | 2            | 11/01/2013| 12/15/2013  
1         | 1            | 12/15/2013| 2/03/2014  
1         | 2            | 2/03/2014 | 3/17/2014  
2         | 6            | 6/21/2014 | 8/25/2014  
2         | 3            | 8/25/2014 | 10/21/2014  
2         | 1            | 10/21/2014| NULL
```

What I need is all of the accounts opened in the last two years and the earliest startDate and caseStatus where caseStatus is either A or B (not for both, whichever was assigned first).  What I keep getting is only the accounts where the minDate is either A or B, which is significantly less.

```
select 
    c.ID, c.Customer, cs.caseStatus  
from 
    m_account_caseStatus m 
left outer join 
    caseStatus cs on m.caseStatusID = cs.ID 
left outer join 
    Account a on m.accountID = a.ID   
where 
    a.dateOpened >= dateAdd(yyyy, -2, getDate()) 
    and caseStatus IN ('A','B') 
    and (a.startDate = (select min(startdate)  
                        from m_account_caseStatus sub1  
                        where sub1.accountID = c.ID))
```

I've re-worked the query several times moving the subquery and caseStatus, but I always end up with only the cases where they started with an A or B status and not all the cases and the date/status where it was first A or B.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: So you want As & Bs if they are on certain date OR they are not As & Bs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;with c as 
(
  select accountID,caseStatusID,startDate,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY accountID ORDER BY startDate DESC) rnk
  from m_account_caseStatus
)

select c.accountID,a.Customer,a.dateOpened,c.caseStatusID,cs.caseStatus,c.startDate
from c 
join Account a on a.ID=c.accountID
join caseStatus cs on cs.ID=c.caseStatusID
where rnk=1 and a.dateOpened>=dateAdd(yyyy, -2, getDate())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @year2 datetime = dateAdd(yyyy, -2, getdate())
select accountID from
(
    -- all A or B accounts withing 2 years
    -- num = 1 (2,3..) is the 1st (2nd, 3rd...) date when account got A or B status
    select 
        m.accountID,
        row_number() over (partition by m.accountID order by startDate) as num
    from 
        m_account_caseStatus m 
        join 
        Account a on m.accountID = a.ID 
    where 
    a.dateOpened >= year2
    and m.caseStatusId in (1,2)
) T
where T.num = 1
```